# Why is selected Object instead of Object[] with primitive array for overloaded methods?

Tags: java, arrays, overloading, primitive

When I run this code:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        someMethod(new int[] {1, 2, 3});
    }

    static void someMethod(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Single object given: " + obj);
    }

    static void someMethod(Object[] objs) {
        System.out.println("Multiple objects given: " + Arrays.toString(objs));
    }
}
```

I get ouput in which `someMethod(Object[] objs)` is selected for `int[]`:

```
Single object given: [I@140e19d
```

I faced with such behaviour when tried to log some message as this:

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "param1: {0}, param2: {1}", new int[] {1, 2});
```

which outputs:

```
...
INFO: param1: [I@103dbd3, param2: {1}
```

So why it is selected Object instead of Object[] as method argument for primitive arrays?

Comment: An `int[]` is not an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because an `int[]` *isn't* an `Object[]` - it's as simple as that. An element of an `Object[]` has to be a reference - and an element of an `int[]` is *not* a reference.

[JLS section 4.10.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3) talks about the subtype relationships for arrays - in particular:

> If `S` and `T` are both reference types, then `S[] >1 T[]` iff `S >1 T`.

Comment: OK, this is not a bug as I thought :) Thanks for spec link.